# Fill listbox from large data in array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a solution for the problem of how to fill the listbox. The problem is that the data is too large (1 million rows and about 20 columns). This code works fine for small amounts of data but for the large data the code takes about 25 seconds for the search process

```
Private Sub TextBox14_AfterUpdate()
Dim a, b(), temp, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Me.ListBox1.Clear
temp = Me.TextBox14.Value
c = ComboBox1.ListIndex
If (c = -1) + (temp = "") Then MsgBox "Specify Search Column First And Make Sure TextBox Is Not Empty", vbExclamation: Exit Sub

a = ws.Range("A1:S" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
ReDim b(1 To 100000)
b(1) = Application.Index(a, 1, 0)

For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    If CStr(a(i, c + 1)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Then
        n = n + 1
        b(n) = Application.Index(a, i, 0)
    End If
Next i

If n > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve b(1 To n)
    If n = 1 Then
        Me.ListBox1.Column = Application.Index(b, 0, 0)
    Else
        Me.ListBox1.List = Application.Index(b, 0, 0)
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

How can I make this run in test way for this large data?

Comment: This may not be a helpful comment for you, but personally I would not use Excel for such a large dataset.

Comment: have you tried first sorting and then filtering?

Comment: @HTH what do you mean by sorting: the sort for the worksheet rows before search ?!!

Comment: No searching: 1) sorting 2) filtering 3) taking visible values which would then be in consecutive cells range

Comment: I don't know but filtering with these large amounts of data manually takes too much time.

Comment: after sorting filtering is lighter. but you might skip it by proper `Find()`

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? .. Although I prefer dealing with arrays because arrays are faster.

Comment: Side note: This _If n > 0 Then_ should be _If n > 1 Then_ given it is the ubound with a fixed lbound of 1